# JQuery: When .each over children with parents with different ID's, the first Parent's ID persists

Tags: jquery, parent

All, I've done my very best to figure this out, though possible examples I've found are far more complicated and it seems as though I'm the only one out there having this problem, so I'm coming to you for help, or perhaps just an explanation.

In the code below, I would expect to see three alerts in a row, tab-1, tab-2, and tab-3, but instead I see three alerts of tab-1.  Why is this and what might be the solution to get the desired effect?

Thanks for your time and assistance.

The HTML

```
<div id="tab-1">
    <span class="test"></span>
</div>
<div id="tab-2">
    <span class="test"></span>
</div>
<div id="tab-3">
    <span class="test"></span>
</div>
```

The jQuery

```
$('.test').each(function() {
    alert($('.test').parent().attr("id"));
});
```

Comment: The same answer 3 times within a minute, good work team!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While your code is close, it's not *quite* right. You should be using:

```
$('.test').each(function() {
    alert($(this).parent().attr("id"));
});
```

[Updated JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/n6Bhh/).

The problem you're experiencing is that you're reselecting the array on each iteration of `each()`, and jQuery will simply return the attributes of the *first* element of the array that's returned.

References:

- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

Answer (score 3):

You're a bit off on your each syntax.

```
$(".test").each(function(index, element) {
    alert($(element).parent().attr("id"));
});
```

This uses the iteration that you're on instead of querying for each test class again and using the first one.

Answer (score 3):

Because you're querying for `$('.test')` instead of using the item in the [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) loop, change it to this

```
$('.test').each(function() {
    alert($(this).parent().attr("id"));
});
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/gLh5z/

You could also use `function(idx, elem)` and then `$(elem)` instead of `$(this)` as the function will be passed the index and element as it's first two parameters.

Comment: Good to know about the index and element.  Thank you.